# When is the apple-app-site-association file being fetched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I have an application on store right now. It did not worked with universal linking. Then I update application and add Apple-app-site-association file in to my website. Re-install the app is likely the solution, but my app is already distributed in App Store, it is unlikely to ask user to delete it and installed again.

Is there any opputunity to let  the iOS or app to fetch my updated apple-app-site-association file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the apple-app-site-association json file ever get updated in app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187576/does-the-apple-app-site-association-json-file-ever-get-updated-in-app)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The short answer is: **Only when the app is installed or updated**.

The good news is that they don't have to delete the app and reinstall it, they can simply update the app and it will re-cache the AASA file. This means that you need to push out a new version ASAP and users that update to that version will cache the newly configured AASA. Otherwise there is no other way to force all devices to

To save yourself the hassle of AASA files, use a 3rd party like [Branch](http://branch.io) (full-disclosure I work there) who will do the AASA handling for you.

Comment: So if we introduce a change in our `apple-app-site-association` but the users do not update their app, iOS will never fetch that file again?