# Apple App Site Association Deny Routes without release

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, aasa

I have an AASA file which is working great so far. Basically it routes everything to go inside my app:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "my.app.id",
        "paths": [
          "/uni/*",
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, every link the user click which has mydomain.com redirects to my app! Which is great so far!

**But** my loved company had the greatest idea to mess with my sleepy nights and decided to release a new product which is working under newproduct.mydomain.com so in the newsletter emails, every time our users tap on a link, it opens my app... although it should be redirected to the web.

What we tried to do is to create a blacklist inside the AASA, but it didn't work... reading around we saw that the user should reinstall the app in order to make it work. The way we did the AASA with blacklist is:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "my.app.id",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /uni/*",
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The solution we are seeing is to threat the link inside the app and if we see is coming from newproduct.mydomain.com we redirect the user to safari, but that will require a release.

My question is... is it possible to make every link in newproduct.mydomain.com to be redirected to the web without an app release?

Comment: AFAIK The app-assiocation-file is cached by OS on app install. So it may work for a fresh install, and not work if the app has been installed before the change

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545302/when-is-the-apple-app-site-association-file-being-fetched